# Querying list within object and How to use IQueryable <List<int>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two objects

```
class Obj1 
{
    int id;
    List<Obj2> Object2;
}

class Obj2 
{
    int id;
}
```

My query with inputId:

```
var Obj2IdList = db.Obj1
    .Where(o => o.Obj1.id== inputId)
    .Select(o => o.Obj2.Select(o2 => o2.id).ToList());
```

I am clearly doing something wrong, I can not simply loop through the IQueryable List of ints and use the ids.

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Naming is important. You seem to have a `DbSet<Obj1> Obj1`. Short non descript names don't help to study things. And don't name a plural property the same as a class.

Comment: When I try to loop through with a foreach compare it with an int

I get told  Cannot be applied to operands of type list<int> and int

Comment: What you want to do at all? What type `Obj2IdList` is supposed to be? Replace `var` with the desired type, that would help to explain your question.

Comment: Its supposed to be a list of ints List<int>, it is however a  IQueryable <List<int>>

Comment: What exactly is `db.Obj1`.  I would assume it's some type of collection of `Obj1` obejcts (maybe even a `DbSet`)  in which case you would not have a `Obj1` property on `o`.  I'd expect you want something more like `db.Obj1s.Whre(o => o.id == inputId).SelectMany(o => o.Object2.Select(o2 => o2.id)).ToList()` to begin with.

Comment: Yes, my problem was that my Query was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

```
var Obj2IdList = db.Obj1
                 .Where(o => o.Obj1.id== inputId)
                 .SelectMany(o => o.Object2.Select(o2 => o2.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think this is the answer! Just going to do some quick testing

Comment: You've got an extra closing parenthesis at the end of that.